# Unable to get the aria-checked attribute of an element in karate

Tags: karate

I have the below html content in my webpage. I need to validate if the aria-checked attribute of a textbox is true using karate. Ideally we can use,

```
<input type="checkbox" role="switch" class="mat-slide-toggle-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-slide-toggle-1-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true">
```

And match attribute("//*[@id='mat-slide-toggle-1-input']", 'aria-checked') == 'false'

but this is throwing the below error

### evaluation (js) failed: attribute("//*[@id='mat-slide-toggle-1-input']", 'aria-checked'), js eval failed twice:document.evaluate("//*[@id='mat-slide-toggle-1-input']", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.getAttribute('aria-checked'), error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"TypeError","description":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')\n    at :1:98","objectId":"-1923954466217830741.1.57"}

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#attribute

I recommend not using XPath as far as possible, CSS is better.

```
* def ariaChecked = attribute('#mat-slide-toggle-1-input', 'aria-checked')
```

Refer other answers for more ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+attribute+ui